# Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive AppComponent

Tags: angular6

I am writing a spec.ts file in angular and getting the following error:

> Failed: Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive
>   AppComponent.

Below is the code I tried

```
import { TestBed, async } from "@angular/core/testing";
    import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

    describe('AppComponent', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [
                    AppComponent
                ],
            });
        });
    });

    it('should create the app', async(() => {
        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    }));``
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you're using a component which includes another components inside. You have to add all the components that you used in `AppComponent` in `declaration` of `configureTestingModule`